# Remove rows with empty lists from pandas data frame

Tags: python, list, pandas, isnull

I have a data frame with some columns with empty lists and others with lists of strings:

```
       donation_orgs                              donation_context
0            []                                           []
1   [the research of Dr. ...]   [In lieu of flowers , memorial donations ...]
```

I'm trying to return a data set without any of the rows where there are empty lists.

I've tried just checking for null values:

```
dfnotnull = df[df.donation_orgs != []]
dfnotnull
```

and

```
dfnotnull = df[df.notnull().any(axis=1)]
pd.options.display.max_rows=500
dfnotnull
```

And I've tried looping through and checking for values that exist, but I think the lists aren't returning Null or None like I thought they would:

```
dfnotnull = pd.DataFrame(columns=('donation_orgs', 'donation_context'))
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df['donation_orgs'].iloc(i):
        dfnotnull.loc[i] = df.iloc[i]
```

All three of the above methods simply return every row in the original data frame.=

Comment: In my experience it is quite perilous to keep data in lists within data frames. It can make grouping and aggregation functions go wrong. If you must do it, consider the tuple instead, that seems to work better.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could try slicing as though the data frame were strings instead of lists:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'donation_orgs' : [[], ['the research of Dr.']],
'donation_context': [[], ['In lieu of flowers , memorial donations']]})

df[df.astype(str)['donation_orgs'] != '[]']

Out[9]: 
                            donation_context          donation_orgs
1  [In lieu of flowers , memorial donations]  [the research of Dr.]
```

Answer (score 86):

To avoid converting to `str` and actually use the `list`s, you can do this:

```
df[df['donation_orgs'].map(lambda d: len(d)) > 0]
```

It maps the `donation_orgs` column to the *length of the lists* of each row and keeps only the ones that have **at least one element**, filtering out empty lists.

It returns

```
Out[1]: 
                            donation_context          donation_orgs
1  [In lieu of flowers , memorial donations]  [the research of Dr.]
```

as expected.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer . Its more elegant

Comment: `df[df['donation_orgs'].map(len) > 0]`, or even `df[df['donation_orgs'].map(bool)]`

Comment: `df[df['donation_orgs'].map(bool)]` this works best as this can even handle null values

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following one-liner:

```
df[(df['donation_orgs'].str.len() != 0) | (df['donation_context'].str.len() != 0)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you read data from a CSV, the other possible solution could be this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', na_filter=True, na_values='[]')
df.dropna()
```

`na_filter` defines additional string to recognize as NaN. I tested this on `pandas-0.24.2`.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that the data type is different, This will help probably

```py
df[df.astype(str)['donation_orgs'] != '[]']
```